# Open axioms of equality

Tags: logic

I have a doubt. I need help.

Can the basic axioms of equality be presented as "open axioms"?

I) (reflexivity)
$\qquad x = x$

II)  (Substitutivity)
$\qquad (x = y) \to \big(F (x, x) \to F (x, y)\big)$

Comment: The convention is that free variable in "axioms" are slapped with a universal quantifier.

Comment: Well, you should also include "symmetry", if x= y then y= x, and "transitivity", if x= y and y= z then x= z.

Comment: @user247327 Symmetry and transitivity can be deduced using reflexivity and suitable instances of substitutivity, provided $F$ is allowed to contain additional variables beyond those exhibited.  For symmetry, if you take $F(a,b)$ in substitutivity to be $b=a$, then substitutivity reads $(x=y)\to((x=x)\to(y=x)$, which, in view of reflexivity, simplifies to $(x=y)\to(y=x)$.  For transitivity, take $F(a,b)$ to be $z=b$. Then substitutivity says $(x=y)\to((z=x)\to(z=y))$.

Comment: In Mendelson's textbook, the substitutivity axiom is as you have written (II). It uses the Hilbert proof system. Notice that $x$ and $y$ are **metavariables** denoting object variables. I believe that this presentation is acceptable because we can generalize variables in these axioms. However, we can't move such axioms to premises of implication by the Deduction Theorem (maybe you need this).

Comment: @beroal - not clear; they are *axioms*: thus, you have no need to use as premises. You van review the def of *deduction* (of a formula $\mathcal C$) *from* $\Gamma$ [page 28]: the (logical) axioms are usable directly as lines in the proof, without listing them in $\Gamma$. In any case, using Gen we can imemdiately retrieve the closed versions of I) and II) [see Mendelson's proof, page 93].

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: A premise of implication is $\mathscr B$ in $\mathscr B\implies\mathscr C$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, cool! Where does one learn this kind of thing?

Comment: @goblin I'm not sure, but I think I learned it from Shoenfield's book "Mathematical Logic".

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can.

Consider the [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) proof system.

We can derive $(x=x)$ from the "closed" version: $\forall x \ (x=x)$ simply using $\forall$-elim rule.

Conversly, from the open axiom $\vdash (x=x)$, we can derive $\vdash \forall x \ (x=x)$ using $\forall$-intro.

There are no assumptions (i.e. $\Gamma = \emptyset$) and thus the proviso of the rule: "$x$ not *free* in $\Gamma$", is satisfied.

---

The open equality axiom $(x=x)$ is obviously *valid*.

See e.g.:

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67), Springer (5th ed. 2013), page 67.

The definition of *true in a structure* $\mathfrak A$ is restricted to *sentences*, i.e. "closed" formulas.

For open ones, it adopts the convention that:

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi \ $  **iff** $ \ \mathfrak A \vDash \text {Cl}
>  (\varphi)$,

where $\text {Cl} (\varphi)$ is the *universal closure* of $\varphi$.

A different approach is adopted by:

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA83), Academic Press (2nd ed. 2001), page 83.

In this case, the meaning and the truth-value of an open formula with respect to an interpretation $\mathfrak A$ is defined for specific "instances" of the formula, obtained through the *variable assignment* device.

The basic notion is that of *satisfaction* of a formula $\varphi$ by an assignment $s$ in a interpretation $\mathfrak A$ (in symbols: $\mathfrak A, s \vDash \varphi$).

A formula $\varphi$ is *true* in $\mathfrak A$ when it is satisfied by every assigment.

Consequently, $(x=x)$ is *true* in every interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mauro ALLEGRANZA.

The use of open instead of closed formulas as axioms comes from Hilbert proof systems which have a rule of inference Universal Generalization statting that $\forall x F(x)$ can be derived from $F(x)$. The rule $\forall$ introduction of Gentzen's Natural Deduction is similar to Universal Generalization.

David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann: Grundzüge der Theoretischen Logik, Springer, Berlin, Germany, 1928 (An English translation was published in 1950, see below)

David Hilbert and Wilhelm Ackermann: Principles of Mathematical Logic, AMS Chelsea Publishing, Providence, Rhode Island, USA, 1950