# What is $x = x$?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let $x$ be an individual variable. What is $x = x$?

An open sentence? Or a true proposition? Well, I think it's an open sentence, due to the presence of the free variable $x$. I do not know if I'm wrong. I ask for help.

Comment: If x is just free then yes it is an open sentence. But in practice you would usually universally quantify it, at which point it is a true proposition.

Comment: @imranfat Real numbers have nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @StefanMesken I beg to differ, unless more info is given (which I am sure there is more to it)

Comment: @imranfat More information is given -- see the tags of the question.

Comment: @StefanMesken Ok then...

Comment: Wouldn't $x==x$ be a true proposition?

Comment: It is a song by Laurie Anderson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4_qdFyVnv8

Comment: It is an [open atomic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Predicate_logic) It is satisfiable, for example if $=$ is interpreted as equality. It is not a valid formula since it is not true in every interpretation. For example, if $=$ means 'kills', it is not necessarily true that $x$ kills $x$.

Comment: See also the previous post [are-there-really-open-axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425902/are-there-really-open-axioms).

Answer (score 2):

In first-order logic, the formula $x=x$ is an open formula, with $x$ as a free variable.  As such, it does not have any truth value in any model unless you substitute a specific value for $x$, or quantify over $x$.  (This particular formula just happens to always turn out to be true if you do substitute a value for $x$, assuming you are working in first-order logic with equality.)

Comment: This assumes that models do not come with variable assignments. That is one common framework. In another common framework, a model comes with a variable assignment, and so *every* formula, open or not, is either true or false in the model.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the particular context is for your question, but one use case is in the reflexivity axiom of equality:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms